# Laravel Eloquent Model use select count(column)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I just want to use the following raw DB query with Laravel Eloquent model.

```sql
SELECT
  <column_name>,
  COUNT(<column_name>) AS `value_occurrence` 

FROM
  <my_table>

GROUP BY 
  <column_name>

ORDER BY 
  `value_occurrence` DESC

LIMIT 1;
```

Let's say I have a model called `TestModel`. I just would like to do something like the following.

```php
TestModel::select('column_name', 'COUNT(column_name) AS occurrences')
           ->groupBy('column_name')
           ->orderBy('occurences')
           ->limit(10)
           ->get();
```

Can you help me please? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that I can use selectRaw to use Count(column_name) in the code however, if there is any better way of doing it, I would like to see it.
Thanks...

**The answer:**

```php
TestModel::selectRaw('column_name, COUNT(column_name) AS occurrences')
           ->groupBy('column_name')
           ->orderBy('occurences')
           ->limit(10)
           ->get();
```